# Case statement in update statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I am trying to update a table. I want to use a case statement to decide what column to update. I keep getting the error message, "syntax error at or near "case"." Can someone please help me find this syntax error. I have been looking all morning:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_PERSON(TARGET_COL INT, UPDATED_VALUE VARCHAR, TARGET_ID CHARACTER)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$ 
    UPDATE PERSON
    SET
    CASE TARGET_COL
        WHEN 1 THEN FIRST_NAME = UPDATED_VALUE WHERE PERSON_ID = TARGET_ID
        WHEN 2 THEN LAST_NAME = UPDATED_VALUE WHERE PERSON_ID = TARGET_ID
        ELSE FIRST_NAME = UPDATED_VALUE WHERE PERSON_ID = TARGET_ID
    END;    
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

A CASE expression can only return a value, not a fragment of a query.

In order to parametrise which column should receive the value passed as an argument, you could try this approach:

```
UPDATE
  PERSON
SET
  FIRST_NAME = CASE WHEN TARGET_COL = 2 THEN FIRST_NAME    ELSE UPDATED_VALUE END,
  LAST_NAME  = CASE WHEN TARGET_COL = 2 THEN UPDATED_VALUE ELSE LAST_NAME     END
WHERE
  PERSON_ID = TARGET_ID
;
```

I slightly simplified the logic, because according to your CASE expression, you want to update `FIRST_NAME` both when `TARGET_COL` is 1 and when it is anything other than 2.  But the second condition actually covers the first one.  So we can simplify the logic to this: if `TARGET_COL` is two, you want to update `LAST_NAME`, otherwise you want to update `FIRST_NAME`.

So how does the above query work?  If `TARGET_COL` is 2, then `FIRST_NAME` is updated to `FIRST_NAME`, i.e. to the same value it already has.  This way it remains unchanged.  In contrast, `LAST_NAME` in this case is set to `UPDATED_VALUE`.  If, however, `TARGET_COL` is not 2 (but e.g. 1), then `FIRST_NAME` gets `UPDATED_VALUE`, while `LAST_NAME` is set to `LAST_NAME` – in other words, remains unchanged.

Comment: I'd write the first case as `FIRST_NAME = CASE WHEN TARGET_COL = 1 THEN UPDATED_VALUE ELSE FIRST_NAME END` just in case they have (or add later) more column to be updated

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: That, in many ways, makes more sense, no doubt.  I chose my approach simply to reflect the logic the OP has shown in the question, but perhaps I should have covered the more sensible one as well.  Maybe I'll add it later.  Thanks for mentioning it anyway.